# One style for one chapter at a time

Tags: koma-script, decorations

*I saw some of the questions that may not answer my question, this question is more on decoration-like aspect.*

When reading some (coloured illustrated) textbooks, one may find that the chapters have different layout styles. Such as the theme colour and icons.

If I would like to have this feature in my document. What should I do.

*If anyone would need a MWE, please request in comment and tell me what sort of MWE is needed. I am not good at providing MWE.*

*Edit:* May I provide some existing examples such as the [IB textbook published by OUP](http://fdslive.oup.com/www.oup.com/oxed/look-inside/9780198392132.pdf?region=international), they provide a sample chapter that is coloured. What I would like is each chapter has different *headings* in different theme colours, and also different *page numbers* with the corresponding colours (which is on the bottom of the page). I don't need to be the same as the example, however.

Comment: Can you please narrow a little the scope of your question? Describe precisely one or two styles that you would want to have.

Comment: Is the edit answers your request?

Comment: I'd be *very* careful with this, changing styles in mid-text can be very jarring.

Comment: @vonbrand I am sorry that I don't quite get it, could you explain it further?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one possibility using [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), [`tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). The code needs three runs to stabilize:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{255,197,51}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{121,163,65}
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{53,78,85}
\definecolor{color4}{RGB}{0,27,92}

% page style - headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyheadoffset[L,R]{2.5cm}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[
    inner sep=0pt,
    fill=\chapterbackcolor,
    font=\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont\color{white}\sffamily,
    text width=1.5cm,
    anchor=south west,
    text height=1.5cm,
    text depth=0.2cm,
    align=center
    ]
    (chapnum) 
    {\thechapter};
   \node[
     fill=\chapterbackcolor,
     anchor=south west,
     font=\color{white}\sffamily
   ] 
   (mark)
   at ([xshift=1em]chapnum.south east) 
   {\leftmark};
   \draw[\chapterbackcolor,line width=1pt] 
     ([xshift=1em]mark.south east) -- ++(\paperwidth,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[OL]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[
    inner sep=0pt,
    fill=\chapterbackcolor,
    font=\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont\color{white}\sffamily,
    anchor=north east,
    align=center
    ]
    (chapimage)
    at (current page.north east) 
    {\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=4cm]{example-image-a}};
   \node[
     inner sep=0pt,
     anchor=south east,
     font=\color{\chapterbackcolor}\sffamily
   ] 
   (mark)
   at ([xshift=-1em]chapimage.south west) 
   {\rightmark};
   \draw[\chapterbackcolor,line width=1pt] 
     ([yshift=-1.5ex]mark.south east) -- ++(-\paperwidth,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[EL]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[
    text width=2cm,
    text height=0.5cm,
    text depth=1.5cm,
    fill=\chapterbackcolor!20,
    font=\Large\sffamily,
    anchor=north east,
    align=center
    ]
    {\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}  
}
\fancyfoot[OR]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[
    text width=2cm,
    text height=0.5cm,
    text depth=1.5cm,
    fill=\chapterbackcolor!20,
    font=\Large\sffamily,
    anchor=north west,
    align=center
    ]
    {\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}  
}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ \MakeUppercase{#1}}}

% chapter style
\newcommand\chapterbackcolor{}

\renewcommand\chapterbackcolor{%
  \ifcase\value{chapter}color4\or color1\or color2\else color3\fi}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\introduction[1]{\def\@introduction{#1}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
  {}
  {0em}
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[fill=\chapterbackcolor,text width=\paperwidth,anchor=north,minimum height=7cm]
      (titleback)
      at (current page.north)
      {};
    \node[font=\huge\color{white},anchor=north west]
      (title) 
      at ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]titleback.north west) 
      {{\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont\thechapter}\quad\MakeUppercase{#1}};
    \node[fill=white,anchor=north west,rounded corners,text width=\the\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm\relax]
      (intro) 
      at ([yshift=-0.5cm]title.south west) 
      {Introduction\\\vspace*{-.35\baselineskip}%
        \begin{minipage}[c][2.2cm][c]{\linewidth}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
          \normalfont\normalsize\@introduction
        \end{multicols}
        \end{minipage}%
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
  {}
  {0em}
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[fill=\chapterbackcolor,text width=\paperwidth,anchor=north,minimum height=7cm]
      (titleback)
      at (current page.north)
      {};
    \node[font=\huge\color{white},anchor=north west]
      (title) 
      at ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]titleback.north west) 
      {\MakeUppercase{#1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\makeatother
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{5cm}

\newcommand\Text{% dummy text just for the example
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus
tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In
hac habitasse platea \columnbreak dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis.
Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed
gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim.
}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage% just for the example

\tableofcontents

\introduction{\Text}
\chapter{circular motion and gravitation}
\section{Circular motion}
\lipsum[1-28]

\introduction{\Text}
\chapter{circular motion and gravitation}
\section{Circular motion}
\lipsum[1-28]

\introduction{\Text}
\chapter{circular motion and gravitation}
\section{Circular motion}
\lipsum[1-18]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The different colors are selected using a `\chapterbackcolor` command that takes its values using a simple `\ifcase` on the value of the `chapter` counter; colors have been defined using `\definecolor` from the `xcolor` package; in its actual form, there's only four colors: one to be used for unnumbered chapters and the other three for the first three numbered chapters. One can simply define more colors and add them in the `\ifcase` clause for more chapters:

```
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{255,197,51}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{121,163,65}
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{53,78,85}
\definecolor{color4}{RGB}{0,27,92}

\renewcommand\chapterbackcolor{%
  \ifcase\value{chapter}color4\or color1\or color2\else color3\fi}
```

All the elements of the chapter titles and the headers were designed basically placing the elements at desired locations using `\node`s inside a `tikzpicture`.

There are still room for improvement: the page numbering for the first page of each chapter (a redefinition of the `plain` page style easily achieved using `fancyhdr` features), a way to change the header image from chapter to chapter but compared to what has been done up to this point, those are easy tasks.

Comment: Error You can't use \dimexpr in restricted horizontal mode.

Comment: Error You can't use \dimexpr in restricted horizontal mode

Comment: @SKKhan Please update your LaTeX system; at least PGF/TikZ. The code I gave works with PGF version 3.0. I edited the answer and the new code should work for you.

Comment: @Ahmad Please see my previous comment. I updated the code so now it should work with older versions of PGF, but please update your packages.

Comment: @Ahmad how i update the PGF packages i am trying but still same error given.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am appreciate to your work, but can you explain how code works when you have time? Or you can just say "please refer to the documentations" is still fine.

Comment: @SKKhan The code with this new update to my answer should work for you without updating.

Comment: @SHY.John I'll add some explanatory comments later.

Comment: @skkhan, follow the steps for manually upgrading the package.

Comment: start>all program> miketex>maintinance admin>package manager admin> filter the pgf package, install the package by right click and install option

Comment: 2nd stp>setting admin> Refresh FNDB and after that update formates.

Comment: now run the above code provided by Gonzalo Medina

Comment: @SHY.John I updated my answer introducing some improvements; I've also added some brief explanatory remarks about the code.

Comment: @SHY.John You're welcome. Don't forget that you can accept an answer that you consider solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to its left; I know you've up-voted (which is great), but accepting is a different action. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Here you are.