# Efficiently use the empty page between \part and \chapter

Tags: chapters, koma-script, parts

No author and their publisher wants to publish a blank page, either do I. In my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181177/customise-to-a-more-fancier-chapter-opening), I have provided the sample page of the opening of `\part` and the opening of chapter as well `\chapter` as well. The layout of the book is like this:

1. The left part of the opening of the `\part`
2. The right part of the opening of the `\part`
3. *(blank)*
4. The opening of the `\chapter`

While I was wondering if input some text into such page 3, a new blank spread is created rather than just used up the blank page. For example,

1. The left part of the opening of the `\part`
2. The right part of the opening of the `\part`
3. **Some text such as prelude**
4. *(blank)*
5. *(blank)*
6. The opening of the `\chapter`

This does not fulfill my original idea, and creates more empty pages.

For one may though a MWE useful, please see below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headinclude,openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\begin{document}
\part{SMAPLE}
Some text
\chapter{SAMPLE}
Some content...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `open=any`?

Comment: Most authors and their publishers publish empty pages nevertheless against their will. Verso pages are almost universally left blank.

Comment: I am sorry that I did not aware of that, my motivation of this question comes from the three pages are decorated, but one page is blanked will become odd compare to the pages beside it. In addition, I want to make a dictum/ prelude on the "blank" page.

Comment: @percusse By the way, the publication will be a desktop one, not printed. However, I am not regarding what you have commented previously in purpose.

Comment: @Johannes_B I just forgot I have used `openright`, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `\partheademptypage`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\renewcommand*\partheademptypage{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\begin{document}
\part{SMAPLE}
Some text
\chapter{SAMPLE}
Some content...
\end{document}
```